# Changing the format of a value based on a function

Tags: sql

Using SQL, I'm trying to group data in a table in 3 dimensions and for that I need a way to modify a value that has been outputted based on some grouping criteria. I then plan to use the GROUP command to finally group the rows together.

It's easier to describe with an example.

I run

```
SELECT b as b_bin
   , l as l_bin
   , k_1AperMag1 as k1_bin
   , count(*) as num
FROM gpssource
WHERE b between -1.1 and 1.1
   and l between 9.9 and 11.6
   and k_1AperMag1 between 0 and 25 
GROUP BY b, l, k_1AperMag1
```

and get a table

```
b_bin               | l_bin              | k1_bin      | num
-1.0115976238979311 | 0.968853586216488  | 13.680575   | 1
-1.0299234557450931 | 11.591887279330654 | 16.761375   | 1
-0.3757959886541285 | 11.446711966673629 | 16.372013   | 1
-0.7250531677528679 | 11.357881248039163 | 17.16921    | 1
...and about 100 million more rows
```

I basically need to bin each row into groups for b_bin, l_bin and k1_bin. For example, the 1st row needs to go into a b bin -1.1 -> -1.0, l bin 0.9 -> 1.0 and k1 bin 13 -> 14. My idea to do this in SQL is to change -1.0115976238979311 to -1.05, 0.968853586216488 to 0.95 and 13.680575 to 13.5 and then use the GROUP by command to actually group them into bins and get a count for each set of bins.

My end result would then be:

```
b_bin | l_bin | k1_bin | num
-1.05 |  0.95 |   13.5 |  23
-0.95 |  0.95 |   13.5 |  20
-0.95 |  0.85 |   13.5 |  25
-0.95 |  0.85 |   12.5 |  23
and more, for each bin in b, l and k1.
```

Eventually, I put it into a matrix and create an image for it with b and l being x and y coordinates and k1 being a slice in 3d space, which leads to something like this (which was created by binning the data in python):
[image: density map of the galaxy]

Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure how to do the change from the actual value to the bin's center value. Is this even possible to achieve with SQL? I have all this working in python but I need to use SQL to bin the data for logistical reasons.

So my basic question is: how do you modify a value that has been printed out by SELECT. I can use format() to format it in a number of ways but as far as I can tell, it doesn't let me pick my own value to output... Does SQL even have functions? I googled for a while and couldn't find much on the matter...

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: What engine are you using for sql: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: What are the sizes of the Bins for each? You mention .1 increments for B and L but K is 1 (13-14)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure to be honest. I'd guess that it is MySQL but it could also be MS SQL. I'd have to ask around. Would the syntax differ a lot?

The bin sizes are constant for the whole data set but they will most likely differ between b, l and k1. I can set them to all be 0.1 but that's not particularly future proof.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Durand can you edit the question to include a sample result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written some SQL to get the results you want here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a54a/1

The following is the code. I'm not sure how well this would perform but you could try it:

```
SET @bbinSize = 0.1;
SET @lbinSize = 0.1;
SET @kbinSize = 1;
SELECT
    bbin,
    lbin,
    kbin,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.b,
        a.l,
        a.k_1AperMag1,
        ((FLOOR(((1 / @bbinSize) * a.b)) * @bbinSize) + @bbinSize / 2) bbin,
        ((FLOOR(((1 / @lbinSize) * a.l)) * @lbinSize) + @lbinSize / 2) lbin,
        ((FLOOR(((1 / @kbinSize) * a.k_1AperMag1)) * @kbinSize) + @kbinSize / 2) kbin
    FROM

    MyTable a
    ) bins
GROUP BY 
    bbin,
    lbin,
    kbin
```

What might be a better idea would be to create three new tables, `BBin`, `LBin` and `KBin` each of which contain three columns `Name`, `MinValue`, `MaxValue`. Then you populate each bin into these.

Your query could then become something like:

```
SELECT
    BBin.Name,
    LBin.Name,
    KBin.Name
    COUNT(*) as MyCount
FROM
    MyTable
    LEFT JOIN BBin ON MyTable.B >= BBin.MinValue AND MyTable.B < BBin.MaxValue
    LEFT JOIN LBin ON MyTable.L >= LBin.MinValue AND MyTable.L < LBin.MaxValue
    LEFT JOIN KBin ON MyTable.KAperMag1 >= KBin.MinValue AND MyTable.KAperMag1 < KBin.MaxValue
GROUP BY
    BBin.Name
    LBin.Name
    KBin.Name
```

I'd suspect the second option would perform better but I'll leave that to you to test.

Comment: Oooh, this looks promising! I'll try it out and let you know. Cheers.

Comment: The first bit of code worked perfectly, thanks a lot! I guess I need to learn more about virtual tables in SQL... Here's a preliminary output image at low resolution: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-si0Hi9R4Wkw/UIbIBGy0v4I/AAAAAAAABao/YeFQbzIvJnc/s896/Screenshot-1.png

I might give the second method a go but that would probably be more tedious when it comes to repeating queries in the future.

Comment: @Durand Glad it worked for you. There's nothing about virtual tables there (I'm not even sure what they are). All I did was a calculation on the values. Im think the algorithm will only work for powers of 10 in the bins, i.e. widths of 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01 etc. It might work for other sizes but I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, by virtual tables, I meant the way you used FROM ( ). I'm not really sure what they are. Nested tables perhaps? I think you're right about the algorithm only working in powers of ten but that's fine for now. Cheers :)